# could not get WebGL context error

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I ran an example code from the documentation page of [`uiaxes`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiaxes.html) on Ubuntu 16.04 glnxa64

```
fig = uifigure;
ax = uiaxes(fig);
x = linspace(-pi,pi,50);
y = 5*sin(x);
plot(ax,x,y)
```

but a JavaScript error is thrown:

[image: Error Message]

How to solve it? Is that because of using Linux?

Comment: Yes it is because Linux

Comment: Is there a way to solve it???